# Cannot install Ubuntu. Error "ACPI PCC probe failed"

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, acpi

I had a Ubuntu partition running just fine alongside my Windows 7 and 10 partitions. Then I went and bought a new video card (EVGA GEforce GTX 950 2GB GDDR5). My computer is custom built. I have a Gigabyte gaming motherboard.

I could only get into Ubuntu because it contained my bootloader but it would not let me into the GUI without my credentials which I am assuming I either forgot or something else was wrong. So I deleted the partition in which Ubuntu was installed. Then I had to fix the MBR in order to boot into Windows.

Once I changed the settings in the BIOS (due to the fact that I could not get windows to load) from onboard graphics to slot 1, I was able to get into my windows partitions and install the drivers. Then, I put my Ubuntu 14.04.3 disk in and prepared to install. It goes to a black screen where I can choose to install or continue without install etc.

I have tried every single option and it brings me back to the `ACPI PCC Probe failed` error message. I even have hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and managed to get into the boot options and tried to turn off `acpi`, `nomodeset`, and `noapic` as well as a combination of these options. Still I get the same message. Nothing is working.